# MacRuby - ActiveRecord for storage?

Tags: ruby, cocoa, macos, activerecord, macruby

Is it possible to use ActiveRecord for storage and query in a MacRuby Cocoa application?

If it is, are there any resources that shows how?

Are there any reason why ActiveRecord should not be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. It's a Ruby library, you can use it without any problem.

However, ActiveRecord is a quite huge library. You might not need all its features. If you simply need to connect to a database and perform operations, I strongly encourage you to give [Sequel gem](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) a try.

Comment: sequal looks interesting! Do you know any pros or cons by using Sequal over Core Data?

Comment: I have some problems with sequel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339601/macruby-error-when-using-sequel

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know Sequel had such kind of incompatibility. You can try also DataMapper. If you don't really need to connect to an external DB but a local persistent storage, then Core Data it's a great solution as well.