# Simple persistence framework compatible with macruby?

Tags: activerecord, macruby, sql

I'm running into problems using macruby with ActiveRecord (w/ sqlite3) or [Sequel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339601/macruby-error-when-using-sequel). Any other suggestions? I need a simple lightweight persistence mechanism to embed within my application that can handle less than 5 tables and at most low tens of thousands of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following combination works:

```
MacRuby 0.8
sqlite3-ruby gem 1.3.2
sequel gem 3.18.0
OSX 10.6.5
```

The trick was uninstalling the 'sqlite3' gem and installing 'sqlite3-ruby'.

Comment: Update: This combination is also working. Macruby (0.11)
sequel (3.21.0)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2)

Comment: This trick doesn't seem to work any more: installing 'sqlite3-ruby' now reports that sqlite3-ruby has been replaced by sqlite3, and it proceeds to install sqlite3. Any workaround?

Comment: Adding this in case someone running Macruby 0.12 sees this. Downgrading sqlite3-ruby and sequel seems to fix the segmentation faults. it's not optimal, but hopefully this will get fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This also works

```
MacRuby 0.12
sqlite3-ruby gem 1.3.2
sequel gem 3.26.0
OSX 10.7.3
```

this is how I found out (not the most efficient way), this can probably be used in the future.

```
(18..35).each do |i|
   print "sudo macgem install sequel --version \"3.#{i}.0\" ; "
   print "macruby -e \"require 'rubygems'; require 'sequel'; p 42\" ; "
   print  "sudo macgem uninstall sequel -I -x ; " 
end
```

Run this on the terminal and look for "42"